# Pevent Facebook Likebox users from leaving my webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-likebox

My need is as following:

- I have an iOS mobile phone with a webview component.
- I use the webview to show my facebook page feeds on the app with **Likebox**
- All works fine but when a user clicks on the links from the likebox it leaves the webpage and get redirected to facebook which is normal **`BUT I WOULD LIKE TO DISABLE THAT FEATURE`**

Can any body help ?

I can do any work arround using: PHP, jQuery

#### ideally I would like to keep like button working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery to intercept the clicks on any link in that div and then have them return false, right?

```
$('#likebox a').click(function() { return false; });
```

Maybe?

Comment: Better would be to use $('#likebox a').on('click', function(event){event.preventDefault();});

Comment: Per dox, that would appear to be a better option (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: hum... I would give it a try, but how about the like button ? I would like to keep it, but the webview doesn't go back to my page after authenticating

Comment: Did you check the like-box dox? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). It would seem the 'like' button is a `<button>` and not an `<a>`, so that code shouldn't affect the like button provided you're just selecting `a` elements :)

Comment: Yes, still the problem of beeng redirected back after authentication in Facebook

Comment: Oh, that I'm not so sure about.. Don't show them content unless they're authenticated already? :P

Comment: I'm not sure of that, thanks anyway, I'll accept if I don't find other ways :)

Comment: If you do, post your method here :) Thanks!